# columns in table with a specific size

Tags: css

what can I do to leave the table as well:
[image]

[image]

I want to make the first column and the last with a specific size and increase the width of the second. My current script css table:

```
<style type="text/css">             
            table
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
                table-layout: fixed;
                width: 200px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
        th, td
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 4px;
        }
    </script>
```

please, tks!

Comment: The easiest way it add the width values into the HTML directly, is that OK?

Comment: add inline style width for the second td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style any of the cells however you like, as follows:

```
/* First cell */
td:first-child {
    width: 40px;
}
/* Second cell */
td:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 150px;
}
/* Last cell */
td:last-child {
    width: 30px;
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/baw07pL1/)